# How to remove a directory path from a text file

Tags: python-2.7

I have a text file with these lines.

1.inputlist

> D:\Dolby_Harmanious_kit\DRY_run_kits\Dolby_Digital_Plus_Decoder_Imp\Test_Materials\Test_Signals\ITAF_Tests\seamless_switch\acmod21_I0D0CRC.ec3 -#tD:\Dolby_Harmanious_kit\DRY_run_kits\Dolby\m1_m28_switch.cfg

2.inputlist

> D:\Dolby_Harmanious_kit\DRY_run_kits\Dolby_Digital_Plus_Decoder_Imp\Test_Materials\Test_Signals\ITAF_Tests\seamless_switch\acmod_2_252_ddp.ec3 -#tD:\Dolby_Harmanious_kit\DRY_run_kits\Digital\m1_m7_switch_every_3frames.cfg

Here i need to remove the path names like

> "D:\Dolby_Harmanious_kit\DRY_run_kits\Dolby_Digital_Plus_Decoder_Imp\Test_Materials\Test_Signals\ITAF_Tests\seamless_switch\"
>   and "D:\Dolby_Harmanious_kit\DRY_run_kits\Digital\ "

.Note that all lines have a different path names.I have a example code to remove a path name.

**Code:**

```
import re
b = open ('Filter_Lines.txt','w')
with open('Lines.txt') as f:
    for trim in f:
        repl = (re.sub('D:.*\\\\','',trim).rstrip('\n'))
        b.write(repl + '\n')

b.close()
```

But here this removes a whole text from "

> D:\Dolby_Harmanious_kit\DRY_run_kits\Dolby_Digital_Plus_Decoder_Imp\Test_Materials\Test_Signals\ITAF_Tests\seamless_switch\acmod21_I0D0CRC.ec3 -#tD:\Dolby_Harmanious_kit\DRY_run_kits\Dolby\"

.I need to remove only path names not including "acmod21_I0D0CRC.ec3" in that line.

Can you please guide me for this.

Comment: do you want to remove entire directory path from your text file which is not similar or path which match your requirements?

Comment: All paths are not similar.

Comment: Now i tried your code, it removes the path before file name and it left the file... like if ur path is, D://your_path/etc.cfg - means your code removes upto  "D://your_path/" and giving filename - "etc.cfg" this is you want ?

Comment: But i have 2 seperate paths in a same line.In that 2 paths contains the file name.Here what to do

Comment: Finally i need output like this " inputlist acmod21_I0D0CRC.ec3 -#tm1_m28_switch.cfg

Comment: please check my answer according to your final output i changed my codes

Comment: I have Updated my requirement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did upto what i understand your question,
here you specified path's are not similar i.e what i understood is,
your path might be

```
a) D://a/b/c/file_name.cfg -#tD://a/b/c/d/e/file_name.cfg
```

is it correct what i understood?

here 2 path present in single line, but common thing is its contains -#t,
so simply use split method to split that.

here what i did based i understand from your post,

```
import re
li = []
b = open ('file_sample.txt','w')
with open ('file_sam.txt') as f:
    for i in open ('file_sam.txt','r'):
        a =  [re.sub('.*\\\\','',i).rstrip('\n') for i in i.split('D:')]
        b.write(''.join(a) + '\n')   
b.close()
```

here my inputs are,

```
'D:\Dolby_Harmanious_kit\DRY_run_kits\Dolby_Digital_Plus_Decoder_Imp\Test_Materials\Test_Signals\ITAF_Tests\seamless_switch\acmod21_I0D0CRC.ec3 -#tD:\Dolby_Harmanious_kit\DRY_run_kits\Dolby\m1_m28_switch.cfg'
'D:\Dolby_Harmanious_kit\DRY_run_kits\Dolby_Digital_Plus_Decoder_Imp\Test_Materials\Test_Signals\ITAF_Tests\seamless_switch\acmod_2_252_ddp.ec3 -#tD:\Dolby_Harmanious_kit\DRY_run_kits\Digital\m1_m7_switch_every_3frames.cfg'
```

it gives me,

```
'acmod21_I0D0CRC.ec3 -#tm1_m28_switch.cfg'
'acmod_2_252_ddp.ec3 -#tm1_m7_switch_every_3frames.cfg'
```

is this you want?

Comment: But i want the output line for first line in same line.

Comment: Can you please help me for this

Comment: According to your question i understand, you want output like this "acmod21_I0D0CRC.ec3 -#tm1_m28_switch.cfg" from your input list is,  D:\Dolby_Harmanious_kit\DRY_run_kits\Dolby_Digital_Plus_Decoder_Imp\Test_Materials\Test_Signals\ITAF_Tests\seamless_switch\acmod21_I0D0CRC.ec3 -#tD:\Dolby_Harmanious_kit\DRY_run_kits\Dolby\m1_m28_switch.cfg   i did according this. here it return the filename only and it removes path... it is not you want means, clarify what you exactly? simply copy your whole txt file and paste it with name and type your expected output you want.. will help based on that

Comment: Now i got output correctly.But i dont need ( ' ) in the lines.

Comment: use split() function to remove that (') . is my answer helped you give accept and up vote to support my answer